# How to simulate a virtual directory in ASP.NET Core app hosted on IIS for debugging?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application hosted on IIS, where I've set up a virtual directory called "attachments" that points to a network share. However, I'm facing difficulties simulating this virtual directory when debugging locally. I've tried using the UseStaticFiles middleware, but it resulted in a 404 error and also broke the static files in the wwwroot folder.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

I added the following code to the Configure method in my Startup.cs file:
csharp

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\server\share\path\to\attachments"),
    RequestPath = "/attachments"
});
```

However, this configuration resulted in a 404 error when accessing the /attachments URL path, and it also affected the static files in the wwwroot folder.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or alternative solutions on how to correctly simulate a virtual directory pointing to a network share when debugging an ASP.NET Core application locally.

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net core does not provide `NetworkCredential` when starting the execution middleware and running to `app.UseStaticFiles`, which will result in inability to access the network share folder.

So the solution should be like below to grant credentials first:

```
    var sourceCredentials = 
        new NetworkCredential { Domain = "domain", UserName = "user", Password = "pass" };
    using (new NetworkConnection("\\\\Network\\Shared", sourceCredentials))
    {
        // to serve static froms from \\network\shared location
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                        Path.Combine("\\\\Network\\Shared"))
        });
    }
```

**Related Link**

[Serve Files from Network Path](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/17/network-path-for-static-files-in-asp-net-core-web-applications/)